# SQL generate a table, count or function for graph

Tags: sql, function, recursive-query

Firstly I have no code to show (but for good reason). I need a pointer or direction before I try again as I have failed a few times already trying to create a recursive function and so on. Kind of given up and thought I would ask you experts as I am lost and stressed.

My Scenario is this.

Im creating a graph in PHP using Json and thats all fine. However the data I need is my issue.

I have records that have a start and an end date.

Example

```
ID  14
Start_Date  03/08/2021
End_Date  07/08/2021
```

Running a stored procedure to grab a records and count between 1 Aug to 10 Aug would display the above as a single record.

Im trying to create a line chart that would have 1 Aug to 2 Aug null then 3 Aug through 7 Aug displaying 1 and finally 8 to 10 Aug null.

```
1 Aug 2021    0  
2 Aug 2021    0  
3 Aug 2021    1  
4 Aug 2021    1  
5 Aug 2021    1  
6 Aug 2021    1  
7 Aug 2021    1  
8 Aug 2021    0  
9 Aug 2021    0  
10 Aug 2021    0
```

Is this possible as I have nearly given up.

The nearest I came was using a loop to create a temporary table and inserting records was NOT pretty and certain was embarrassing. If I recreated and posted it here I would die of shame for sure.

So if anyone can point me in the right direction, offer a suggestion or anything like this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with a list of dates.  There are many ways to generate such a list -- perhaps you have an existing table, or your database supports a function.  SQL (in general) supports recursive CTEs, which is an alternative method.

Once you have the dates, you can use `left join` and `group by` to get the counts you want.  Here is an example using MySQL syntax:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2021-08-01') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < '2021-08-10'
     )
select d.dte, count(t.id)
from dates d left join
     t
     on d.dte between t.start_date and t.end_date
group by d.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d072eaa25768a44e9cd6dd0deb70c7a6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, that is excellent ! I cannot express how happy I am right now, been looking at this now for the best part of a week and Im a wreck.